# How to access external files in a custom library with virtual environment?

Tags: python

I finished installing the custom library in the virtual environment with setup.py,
I got an error,How to access external tools:
'/Users/xmly/PycharmProjects/aiautotest/airtest/core/android/static/adb/mac/adb'

```
File "/Users/xmly/venv/aiautotest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiautotest-1.0-py3.7.egg/airtest/core/android/adb.py", line 189, in cmd
    proc = self.start_cmd(cmds, device)
  File "/Users/xmly/venv/aiautotest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiautotest-1.0-py3.7.egg/airtest/core/android/adb.py", line 168, in start_cmd
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/xmly/PycharmProjects/aiautotest/airtest/core/android/static/adb/mac'
```

this is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
setup(
    name='aiautotest',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'aiautotest': ["config/*"],
        'airtest': ["report/*", "core/android/static/*"]
    },
    entry_points="""
    [console_scripts]
    aiautotest = aiautotest.__main__:main
    """,
)
```

Packaging and installation are successful

```
python setup.py bdist_egg
python setup.py install
```

Is there a way to access external files？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

’./mac' is a folder, not a file, which causes such an error.